# Looping in tableview for Parse data

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I have the following problems when I fetch data from Parse for my tableview:

1. If I have 3 sections, it loops all content for each of the 3 sections.
2. My titleforheader always show the first section title.
3. I already use objectEnumerator() but it varies differently when I click in each time.

Here's my current code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    cata(Item as NSString)

    for i in 1...self.sec
    {
        loadData(i)
    }

}


func loadData(i:Int){

    self.timelineData.removeAllObjects()

    var findTimelineData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "category")
    findTimelineData.whereKey("type", equalTo:"\(Item)")
    findTimelineData.whereKey("section", equalTo:i)
    findTimelineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!)->Void in

        if error == nil{
            for object in objects{
                let sweet:PFObject = object as PFObject
                self.timelineData.addObject(sweet)
                let array:NSArray = self.timelineData.objectEnumerator().allObjects
                self.timelineData = NSMutableArray(array: array)
                println(array)
            }
        }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String {


    var query = PFQuery(className: "category")
    query.whereKey("type", equalTo:"\(Item)")
    query.whereKey("section", equalTo:1)
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (object: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            println("Successfully retrieved ")

               let name = object["title"] as String
            self.name = name

        } else {

            NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo!)
        }
    }

   return name
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set different table header section title name in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719514/how-to-set-different-table-header-section-title-name-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to always ask for section 1?

```
query.whereKey("section", equalTo:1)
```

Should this not be:

```
query.whereKey("section", equalTo:section)
```

Comment: But i have no idea how to make the loop correctly so that i won't be deplicate